# mysql query: select related record depending on column values

Tags: mysql

I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around a query for this scenario:

tbl1 and tbl2 are left joined
i want to select the record from tbl2 based on what multiple records may exist.

tbl2 has columns A and B. I need to select the record where: 
A = 0 and B = 1 or
A = 1 and no related record where B = 1 exists

the result should only have one record from tblB -- so a straight "OR" doesn't work. the criteria is based on the potential existence of another record.

Answer (score 0):

> the result should only have one record from tblB -- so a straight "OR" doesn't work.

Actually, it does. `left join ... on A = 0 and B = 1 or A = 1 and B is null`. What you then need to do is eliminate the duplicates with the `distinct` operator.

Comment: that's not quite the scenario i described. i don't need B is null. i need to determine there are no other related records where B = 1. the logic needs to determine which one of many related records is returned.

Comment: In this case `left join Btbl on a = 0 and b = 1` where `a = 0 and b = 1 or a = 1 and b is null`